# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException while opening .docx or .doc file from web

Tags: android, android-webview

I am getting below error when I try to open .docx or .doc or .txt files from web but I don't see this exception and I can open the file if the file type is .pdf or .jpg

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
 Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://10.0.2.2:8081/... typ=application/msword flg=0x14000000 (has extras) }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1809)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4507)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4475)
    at com.example.test.OpenFileTask.openDoc1(OpenFileTask.java:89)
    at com.example.test.OpenFileTask.doInBackground(OpenFileTask.java:24)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Below is the url
http://10.0.2.2:8081/test/download/Test.doc?ticket=255c000161_word_l5906nc7ggozg.doc

Browser downloads the file if I use above url in browser

Below is the code that I am using in **MainActivity.java**

```
Uri path = Uri.parse(url);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String mimeType = getMimeType(url);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, mimeType);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
```

manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/test_app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="android.webkit.WebView.MetricsOptOut"
               android:value="true" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I am not able to understand how come above code works for .pdf/.jpg files and is not working for .doc or .docx or .txt files. I haven't yet tested for ppt and xlsx files

I have both google docs and OfficeSuite apps installed on my device.

I am new to android development any help is much appreciated

Comment: I am using android webview and I have not posted the activity xml. Is it really required to post it here? It has simple WebView element thats it. Without using WebView how can I load webpage in Android app.

Comment: If you use a tag in your question, I *expect* some reference to it in your question,otherwise the tag is misleading. Your not *required* to do anything, it just helps other people to understand your question, if you share what you can, a wider audience gets you more exposure, and more balanced answers. People use tags to search for questions they might have some input on.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the apps that you have installed are capable of viewing local files, but are not capable of downloading them from the Internet. Download the file yourself (e.g., via OkHttp), set up `FileProvider` to make the files available, then use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to get the `Uri` to use in your `Intent`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought of above suggested approach but if users  will be working on lot of files and if they keep on downloading the files then their phone may run out off space. Do you have  any other recommendation? Also what surprises me is it works for .pdf and .jpg files

Comment: @Mohan: "Do you have any other recommendation?" -- no. "Also what surprises me is it works for .pdf and .jpg files" -- there are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across ~10,000 device models. Do not assume that every one of those ~2 billion devices will have an activity that responds to `ACTION_VIEW` for an `http`/`https` `Uri` for PDF or JPEG files. Also, do not assume that those activities that *do* honor that structure somehow magically consume no disk space for the downloaded content.